# How are failed documentation tags dealt with?

Tags: discussion, tags, documentation

Some of the documentation tags just do not get enough attention. It could be for different reasons. Sometime there is a different tag stealing all the attention.

Some of those cases could be easily fixed with tag aliasing. But for others it is not as straight-forward.

For example there is [`adb`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/adb) and there is [`android`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android) which has a much more active [`android-debug-bridge`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1051/adb-android-debug-bridge) subtopic.

I think those two should be somehow merged.

Answer (score 10):

ADB topic in Android clearly violates recommendations on the number of examples per topic. I think the best approach would be:

1. Split topic into multiple topics.
2. Move all subtopics into ADB tag.
3. Remove redundant topics and examples.

The reason for Android's topic greater success compared to the separate tag is that it's easier to find, as Android is at the top of the tag list, so all topics in it receive more attention. And even if somebody finds the ADB tag, they likely find out that it's behind the topic in Android, so there's no motivation to improve it.

Moving content into a separate tag, while reducing visibility somewhat, should raise the tag thanks to upvotes, offsetting the lost visibility. People are expected to use search (either internal site search or external search engine) to find interesting content to read and improve. So in the long run, visibility shouldn't be harmed.

Considering there're no tags (like in Q&A), no topic hierarchy, and overall Documentation is lacking organization, it would be easier to navigate ADB related content if it's in a separate tag.

Comment: I wish there were more topic hierarchy so that things like adb could be discovered without search. But since there isn't, your approach sounds good.

Comment: I agree with your recommendation, though I'd consider leaving a simple topic in the Android tag, with links to the ADB section.